# Not able to fetch Sharepoint List data using CAML query

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to fetch data from SP list using the CAML query listed below.

**CAML Query**

```
oQuery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='" 
    + jTitleMappingList.Fields["SET Area"].InternalName + "'/>"
    + "<Value Type='LOOKUP'>" + ddlSubsite.SelectedValue
    + "</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

**Error Message Faced:**

> {Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: One or more field types are not
>   installed properly. Go to the list settings page to delete these
>   fields. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x81020014):
>   One or more field types are not installed properly. Go to the list
>   settings page to delete these fields.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPrevCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pFilterLinkCallback, ISPDataCallback pSchemaCallback, ISPDataCallback
>   pRowCountCallback, Boolean& pbMaximalView)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection.EnsureListItemsData()    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.PopulateReturnedFieldsSafeArray()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.EnsureFieldsSafeArray(Boolean
>   bGetFullXML)    at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.get_Count() 
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldCollection.get_Item(Int32 iIndex)    at
>   AZ.SharePoint.RST.AddUsersFromExcelUtility.RSTArchiveSetArea.RSTArchiveSetAreaUserControl.b__0()}

I have tried creating a custom view with columns getting added one-by-one but it did not work out as well for finding the column with the issue. And also have tried adding the column with internal name for referring the CAML query filter but after that too the query does not fetch the required results.

Comment: can you show us the actual CAML query you used?

Answer (score 1):

That error message typically means that there is something wrong with the syntax of your CAML query.

- CAML can be sensitive to character casing. Try changing `Type='LOOKUP'` to `Type='Lookup'`
- Make sure that the value of `jTitleMappingList.Fields["SET Area"].InternalName` resolves to the actual internal name of one of the fields on your list
- Make sure that the column you are filtering against is actually a Lookup column, and not some other column type

Answer (score 0):

well not sure how you constructed your query, but here's a small example of how it should be :

```
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='SharePointFielName' /><Value Type='Text'>" + ddlSubsite.SelectedValue +</Value></Eq></Where>";
```

This link might help you better understand;

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list.getitems(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I have tried using the below listed CAML query but still no results are getting fetched as shown below.

Comment: I have tried using the below listed CAML query but still no results are getting fetched as shown below.   CAML Query used is as shown here : "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='SET_x0020_Area' LookupId='TRUE'/><Value Type='Lookup'>Donna T3</Value></Eq></Where>".  The particular site is available in the list.